# How to know is a particular record is present in database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

How would I know if a particular data is present in database or not? For E.g. If the Database already has "Student_Id" and "Course_Id" in a table then update the record else insert the record.

I already have a controller action which I use to insert the data, but I want to add an additional feature where it checks the database (SQL Server) and does insert/update based on whether the record is present or now.

I use Linq to SQL to insert data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are Student_id and Course_id generated?

Comment: Check out this stackoverflow answer


[if exists statement in sql to linq][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476214/if-exists-statement-in-sql-to-linq

Comment: @Maess They are generated by a different system. None of them are primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **could** check if the data is there via a simple select statement, prior to adding the data.

```
bool exists = yourTable.Any(row => row.StudentID == studentId && row.CourseID = courseID);
```

Ideally though, you should design the database to make `Student_Id` and `Course_Id` a combined unique key for this table, so your code won't be able to add them at all if a record is already there.

As Maess asked, how are the values being generated? Your options could change depending on whether the data is user-generated or not. For example; if you have two dropdown boxes to select a student and a course, don't allow the user to select a course that the student is already diong.

Comment: `Any` also takes a predicate. Makes `Where` redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use LinqToSql I would do something like

```
var item = (from c in dataContext.TableName
           where c.StudentID == your_sid && c.CourseID== your_course_id
           select c).FirstOrDefault();


if(item==null)
{
   //insert the record
}
else
{
   //update the record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the record with a `.FirstOrDefault()`, if null, insert, then update values and `.SubmitChanges()`.