# VB ASP.NET check if data is in table if yes, update, else insert

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, insert-update, upsert

I have looked through the *entire* internet (well that's what it feels like) to find this out.

Tables - Authors and Titles

add new title must be linked to an author, so I need to check that the author exists, if so, update the titles table with the user data from the textboxes.  If the author does not exist, I need to insert the author first & last name into the author table, then the title info into the title table.

this is in VB, using ASP.NET, and my database is a file, I'm not using SQL server, just Visual Studio 2008.

Many thanks in advance for any guidance

```
Dim insertParameters As New ListDictionary()

insertParameters.Add("ISBN", ISBNTextBox.Text)
    insertParameters.Add("Title", titleTextBox.Text)
    insertParameters.Add("EditionNumber", editionNumberTextBox.Text)
    insertParameters.Add("Copyright", copyrightTextBox.Text)
    insertParameters.Add("FirstName", firstTB.Text)
    insertParameters.Add("Surname", secondTB.Text)

 LinqDataSource1.Insert(insertParameters)
```

Comment: It depends the structure of your file. We need some more information on this to help you.

Comment: its a basic .mdf with 3 tables (Author, Title & Publisher) and 2 joiner tables (author ISBN - with author ID and ISBN and a concat key and publisherISBN - with publisherID and ISBN as a concat key)

Comment: how did you created tables on `.mdf` file and how you are retrieving it?

Comment: LinqDataSource1.Insert(insertParameters)                          this is what I used in another section to insert all the parameters I declared, but this time I want to check, then either update or insert to different tables

Comment: The first table was provided in a file and I added the others via visual studio.  I am retrieving it with a LINQDataSource

Comment: @Amy can you post some sample code please?

Comment: AFK - back in a couple of hours

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you should take a step back to get the big picture. Here is a link to a video to get you started on LinqToSQL http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zy4Y34brSC8&feature=related. The reason I say that is it appears as though you might be missing the fundamentals and trying to put the cart before the horse so to speak. And here is a link to the MS documentation which I believe should really help you in the long run http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you Craig but neither of these links help me. I know how to update or insert independently but not concurrently for two different tables

Comment: @Amy I think the lack of responses is due to the lack of clarity in your question. The term concurrently, would be ideal in your question. Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476214/if-exists-statement-in-sql-to-linq

Comment: That is almost what i am looking for. But in vb not c# I'm sorry my question was vague, I'll do better next time!